# python cannot debug after using pyarmor

Tags: python, debugging, pyarmor

A python file import another file using pyarmor-package. As a result, I cannot debug all the code after the import. How can I solve this problem

Comment: pyarmor is used to make debugging difficult; the solution is to see if you are able to get the original source and modify it to not use pyarmor.

Comment: thanks, I will try to find other code